# Could a wormhole exist on a planet?

Tags: physics, black-holes, wormholes

For my story to work, my characters have to stumble across a small wormhole that actually exists *on Earth* and is responsible for multiple disappearances throughout history. It connects a point on Earth to a point on a life-sustaining planet far from our solar system, and possibly not in our galaxy (haven't decided yet). Is this possible, either naturally or artificially? Further, if the wormhole were to collapse, would the only outcome be for two black holes to be created on either side, or could it be "taken down" if it were created artificially?

NOTE: This story takes place in a time very similar to present (maybe 20, 30 years in the future) but the technology involved has the capacity to be far more advanced.

Comment: Schwarzchild wormhole connecting two points in the same universe is unstable meaning even photon isn't fast enough to get through unless you apply negative energy and lots of it.

Comment: Maybe think of it in reverse, if it exists then any scientific theory that says otherwise is wrong, incomplete or does not apply.

Comment: @NPSF3000: I don't think the science community excludes the possibility of wormholes it just that they have yet to observe one in the wild.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I've been working with wormholes and portals extensively with my writing and can probably give you some pointers. I'll be describing them as portals from here on. **It's also important to note these portals reduce the distance from one point to another to 0**, meaning I take one step and feel no different than normally walking, yet I just crossed light years of space.

I have two kinds of portals that work. **One only requires creation and stability at one end**, so you could make a connection from, say one solar system to another. This has to be done outside of the system, so generally around the region of the kuiper belt or farther (please note this depends on the system in question, you would be able to do so closer or farther if the solar environment allows for it). This system needs a massive power source in order to maintain the portal, but it is possible. It's also quite safe, just don't touch the edges of the portal.

The **other kind uses two connection couplings**. Structures that pull the portal open while pouring power through to stabilize it. These tend to give off lots of excess energy, something detectable by today's standards.

**If the portal is naturally occurring**, then there's a reason and it's probably very big. A man made portal that loses power simply collapses and disperses with everything returning to normal since there's no energy to do anything else. A natural portal would take such immense energy that even being nearby would probably be fatal. **So if it's not a natural portal, it wouldn't end up being a black hole after it closes**.

**If instead you are talking about a place were there is a convergence in the dimensions that allows for accidental transfer**, then this might work. Basically through issues in the surrounding dimensions the local space is weak, and it would look very strange. Odd lights and hues of different colors dancing around, sense of direction would be lost, gravity would behave strangely and so forth.

Also please note: Creation of portals across vast distances takes lots and lots of energy, I'm talking the power of the stars here. The longer the distance, the less viable it is. A very long distance portal, say between galaxies, is unlikely then. After all, if you can create such a thing, why bother with Earth? I'd find your story more likely in this sutation if the connection point was at least in the solar interstellar neighborhood (which is a real thing).

For your story, any of the following work:

- The portal is opened by a long forgotten starship AI that's crashed on a planet, trying to find help
- The portal is like a trap, to lure people from one planet to another for reasons you can work out
- Somehow the wrong coordinates keep getting input wrong in whoever's portal creation system, breaching intergalactic law about contact with primitive people
- To close the portal, you have to get some high energy output device so it can't maintain it's shape. However, said portal is not only underground but well defended. Maybe earth is being slowly invaded?

Answer (score 0):

The sci-fi wormhole is not limited to being far away from a planet. Any scheme of moving wormhole mouths after creation implies that they can he "handled" as well as traversed.  This is usually not elaborated upon.  So having it in your basement, being dragged along with the Earth's rotation, would use the same "holder".

Answer (score 0):

wrt Hard Science, it is not possible. In fiction you may have a wormhole the way you like it. [Primeval](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0808096/) is a good start. In this TV series (very popular at 7.3 rating) wormholes start appearing around London every now and then.

Now this is not possible in normal conditions the likes of which prevail on our planet, but since it is an entertainment series, so it's acceptable. You don't have to make your novel/movie/game a science documentary. Make things be the way you like. That's the rule of thumb in fiction. Just make them interesting, that's the main point.